# Last known location and current location cannot be retrieved on some devices

Tags: java, android, gps, android-gps

We have launched an Android app that utilizes GPS information and a minority of our users report that GPS is not working for them. Although we have invested a lot of time to improve the codebase we still have not been able to provide relevant improvements to the affected users. We are now looking for fresh ideas from the community to make a step forward and resolve this. Thanks for your feedback in advance!

## Approach

In our Android app we are identifying the users location in three sequential steps:

1. Current GPS location (GPS_PROVIDER)
2. Current network location (NETWORK_PROVIDER)
3. Last known GPS location (GPS_PROVIDER)

If one step fails, the next step is attempted. If none of the steps succeed an GPS-errormessage is shown to the user.

## Issues

A minority of users report they **always** receive the GPS-errormessage. Together with the users we have tried the following actions but without any success:

- Ensuring that GPS is enabled on the device
- Ensuring that GPS permissions are given to the app (fine grained location)
- Closing the app, getting current location on Google Maps, then restarting the app

## Code

This is the code that we have in place. The app calls GeoRepository.getCurrentLocation(..).

```
public class GeoRepository {
private static final String TAG = GeoRepository.class.getSimpleName();

public GeoRepository() {
}

public class GeoNoPermissionException extends RuntimeException {
    public GeoNoPermissionException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
public class GeoNoLocationException extends RuntimeException {
    public GeoNoLocationException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}

public interface GeoLocationListener {
    void onCompleted(Location location);
    void onFailed(RuntimeException ex);
}

public void getCurrentLocation(Context context, GeoLocationListener listener) {
    // The permissions for this is already being requested in the SplashActivity
    boolean hasPermission = !(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    if (!hasPermission) {
        listener.onFailed(new GeoNoPermissionException("Missing permissions", null));
        return;
    }

    // try initially with precise GPS provider
    requestLocationOnce(context, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, new GeoLocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Location location) {
            listener.onCompleted(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(RuntimeException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not find location on first attempt", ex);
            requestLocationOnce(context, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, new GeoLocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Location location) {
                    listener.onCompleted(location);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailed(RuntimeException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not find location on second attempt", ex);

                    Location location = null;
                    try {
                        location = requestLastKnownLocation(context, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    } catch(RuntimeException ex2) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Could not find location on third attempt", ex2); 
                        /* !!! this is where we hit the wall and return a GPS-errormessage to the user !!! */
                        listener.onFailed(ex);
                        return;
                    }
                    if(location == null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Could not find location on third attempt, location is null");
                        listener.onFailed(ex);
                        return;
                    }

                    listener.onCompleted(location);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private void requestLocationOnce(Context context, String provider, GeoLocationListener listener) {
    // The permissions for this is already being requested in the SplashActivity
    boolean hasPermission = !(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    if (!hasPermission) {
        listener.onFailed(new GeoNoPermissionException("Missing permissions", null));
        return;
    }

    Object syncObj = new Object();
    CountDownLatch completedSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) FlourishApp.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // this method may never get called hence we need a watchdog later on
            // this happens for example if GPS permissions are there but GPS is turned off
            synchronized(syncObj) {
                if (completedSignal.getCount() > 0) {
                    completedSignal.countDown();
                    listener.onCompleted(location);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };

    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(
            provider,
            locationListener,
            Looper.getMainLooper());

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
        // cleanup event subscription
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

        // watchdog to raise error if we don't get a callback within reasonable time
        boolean receivedLocationUpdate = true;
        synchronized (syncObj) {
            if (completedSignal.getCount() > 0) {
                completedSignal.countDown();
                receivedLocationUpdate = false;
            }
        }

        if(!receivedLocationUpdate) {
            GeoNoLocationException ex = new GeoNoLocationException("No location could be determined", null);
            listener.onFailed(ex);
        }
    }, Constants.LOCATION_MAX_WAIT); // LOCATION_MAX_WAIT = 50000
}

private Location requestLastKnownLocation(Context context, String provider) {
    // The permissions for this is already being requested in the SplashActivity
    boolean hasPermission = !(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    if (!hasPermission) {
        throw new GeoNoPermissionException("Missing permissions", null);
    }

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) FlourishApp.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
}

public interface GetCountryCodeByCurrentLocationListener {
    void onCompleted(String countryCode);
    void onFailed(RuntimeException ex);
}
}
```

## Devices

The affected users have been using one of these devices:

- Huawei P8
- Oppo CPH1723
- Galaxy Note4

## Thoughts

- Could it be that the users simply were offline which caused this issue? No this should have been ruled out by testing with Google Maps and by utilizing last-known-location as well.
- Could it be that device settings are to be blame? No this has been ruled out by testing with Google Maps.
- Could it be that app permissions are to be blame? No this has been clarified with the users.
- Could it be that our code is bugy? Maybe but we cannot identify any obvious flaws.
- Did you try some alternative providers? Yes we tried the newer Fused Location Provider API as well and the very same issues happened.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the details of the GPS-errorMessage you are talking about?

Comment: Hey there, this is an error that we Display to the user. The point where this error is raised is shown in the code, please see the following comment in the code: /* !!! this is where we hit the wall and return a GPS-errormessage to the user !!! */

Answer (score -1):

LastKnownLocation almost always fails.  It only works if the location service was previously turned on by another app (or your own) recently enough that the value was cached.  The phone doesn't actively track location at all times.  99% of the time when you call it, you will get null returned.  So if 1 and 2 failed, there is zero chance that 3 is going to work.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the exact reason for this. Kindly check for the below points too.

- Are you following GPS request Guidelines for Android 8 [See this link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits)
- Battery Saving Mode is Turned Off?
- Is the target device updated with current google support library?

Also increase number of times you request for location update, in some devices i have experienced this since the first one or two times the location data is null.